# Find the differential of this function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

$$y'= \left(\frac{y+2}{x+y-1}\right)^2$$

So, i've been struggling with this for about 4 days, and sure, call me names, math is not my stronger suit, but I'd really like to figure this out. I've tried all sorts of approaches, to separate it, to get it on homogeneous equation, but i always get stuck, and can't get around.
I'd really appreciate your help and some tips on how should I approach it.

Comment: you want to solve this equation?

Comment: First things first: no one here is going to call you names for not knowing something. This site is set up for people to ask for help and to help each other.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to solve it. Im practicing for my math exam, and this just gives me headaches.

Oh, and im sorry, i didnt mean to be rude. Thanks <3

Comment: What about using the sustitutions $t=x-3$ and $r=y+2$? These give us the DE
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\left(\frac{r}{t+r}\right)^2$$
Which is homogeneous.

Comment: Yes, i've tried that, too. But after that is what bothers me. What to do next? And if I put $r^2$ and $(t+r)^2$ then i will have $t^2 + 2tr + r^2$ and i don't know how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the sustitutions $t=x-3$ and $r=y+2$ the DE becomes
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\left(\frac{r}{t+r}\right)^2\tag{1}$$
Which is homogeneous. So lets put $r=ut$, then DE $(1)$ converts to
$$u+t\frac{du}{dt}=\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)^2\tag{1'}$$
Now perform algebraic manipulations:
\begin{align*}
\frac{du}{dt}&=\frac{u^2-u(1+u)^2}{(1+u)^2t}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{-u^3-u^2-u}{(1+u)^2t}\\[3pt]
\frac{u^2+2u+1}{u(u^2+u+1)}\frac{du}{dt}&=-t^{-1}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Integrating both sides of eqn $(2)$ we get
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{u^2+2u+1}{u(u^2+u+1)}\frac{du}{dt}dt&=\int-t^{-1}dt\\[3pt]
\int\left(\frac1u+\frac1{u^2+u+1}\right)du&=\int-t^{-1}dt\qquad\\[3pt]
\log|u|+\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2u+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)&=-\log|t|+c\\[3pt]
\log\left|\frac{y+2}{x-3}\right|+\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2(y+2)}{\sqrt{3}(x-3)}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)&=-\log|x-3|+c
\end{align*}

So
$$\log|y+2|+\frac2{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2(y+2)}{\sqrt{3}(x-3)}+\frac1{\sqrt3}\right)=c$$

Comment: Putting $r=ut$ I get that the left hand side becomes $u+t\dot{u}$, not $u+\dot{u}$ as you've put.

Comment: Thank you so much! It really helped me understand what was I doing wrong. Thanks again.